# Flink Stream Sink ParquetWriter Failing with ClassCastException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, parquet

i have Written a consumer that read from kafka topic and write the data in parquet format using StreamSink . But i am getting following error

```
java.lang.Exception: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.checkThrowSourceExecutionException(SourceStreamTask.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.performDefaultAction(SourceStreamTask.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.run(StreamTask.java:298)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:403)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:530)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:651)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:612)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:592)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:727)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:705)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collect(StreamSourceContexts.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSourceContexts$NonTimestampContext.collectWithTimestamp(StreamSourceContexts.java:111)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.AbstractFetcher.emitRecordWithTimestamp(AbstractFetcher.java:398)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaFetcher.emitRecord(KafkaFetcher.java:185)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaFetcher.runFetchLoop(KafkaFetcher.java:150)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:715)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:202)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.CharSequence
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.fromAvroString(AvroWriteSupport.java:371)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.writeValueWithoutConversion(AvroWriteSupport.java:346)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.writeValue(AvroWriteSupport.java:278)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.writeRecordFields(AvroWriteSupport.java:191)
    at org.apache.parquet.avro.AvroWriteSupport.write(AvroWriteSupport.java:165)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.write(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:128)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter.write(ParquetWriter.java:299)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.ParquetBulkWriter.addElement(ParquetBulkWriter.java:52)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.BulkPartWriter.write(BulkPartWriter.java:50)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Bucket.write(Bucket.java:214)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.Buckets.onElement(Buckets.java:268)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink.invoke(StreamingFileSink.java:370)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.processElement(StreamSink.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:637)
```

code is simple :

```
DataStream<GenericRecord> sourceStream = env.addSource(bikeDetailsKafkaConsumer010;

            final StreamingFileSink<GenericRecord> sink = StreamingFileSink.forBulkFormat
                    (path, ParquetAvroWriters.forGenericRecord(SchemaUtils.getSchema(schemaSubject)))
                    .withBucketAssigner(new EventTimeBucketAssigner())
                    .build();

            sourceStream.addSink(sink).setParallelism(parallelism);
```

Is it something wrong with some record and how to debug that which record is giving exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a `ClassCastException` while writing Parquet/Avro, it's almost always the case that schema and data do not match.

I recommend to print out the expected schema and the actual record formatted as json (either with `toString` or even better with type information).

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
JsonEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(schema, baos);
writer.write(genericRecord, encoder);
encoder.flush();
baos.flush();
return new String(baos.toByteArray());
```

Comment: But if schema and record do not match then how the record can pass validation and push to topic . it should fail at the producer side only and should not get push to topic.

Comment: Also i am able to parse the record with same schema only when writing i am getting error.

Comment: No the records in Kafka are fine, but the schema while writing parquet is not matching.

Comment: ok Arvid but its happening very randomly and i am using same schema to write in kafka , read it  and write in parquet then how it possible. schema is in kafka schema registery than only i am using to write in parquet. like this           List<Integer> versions = registryClient.getAllVersions(subjectName);
 SchemaMetadata schemaMeta = registryClient.getSchemaMetadata(subjectName, versions.get(versions.size() - 1));
   Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaMeta.getSchema());

Comment: and even its happening than how can i skip that record and continue so that my whole job not get failed and stopped consuming because of a single record.

Comment: Are you sure that all records use the same/compatible schemas? And please update your question instead of putting all information into comments.

Comment: yes we always pushing with latest schema and consuming with latest version only. Can you please help me to implement a way to skip records if this is happening as currently parquet sink stuck in loop of checkpoint. i want to skip and continue.